# How to specify a face on a mesh in gltf?

Tags: three.js, gltf

I want to be able to reference a specific face on a specific mesh in a glTF file. I am confused by the notion of primitives however. Normally, I would use the face index (ie, in three.js) and I would always be able to reference the same face. However, sometimes meshes in glTF have multiple primitives. Do these use the same face buffer? Do they at least use consecutive face buffers? I am wondering if I can reference a face in a mesh using just one number (ie, a face index) or if I need to also use a primitive index.

Do mesh primitives share a pool of vertices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two glTF primitives in a single mesh could be related, or unrelated, the same ways as two glTF meshes each containing a single primitive. Two primitives could have:

- same vertex attributes but different indices.
- same vertex attributes AND indices, but different materials.
- no shared vertex attributes or indices
- entirely different draw modes (POINTS, LINES, TRIANGLES, ...)

So unless you're fully in control of the files you're loading, the default and safest assumption would be to treat each primitive as a completely separate mesh. If there are more specific cases you want to check for (like the first two bullets above), you can always add that as a later optimization.

If you're loading a glTF file into threejs, each primitive will become a separate `THREE.Mesh` under a common `THREE.Group`.

For further details, see the [glTF specification section on Meshes](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/2.0/README.md#meshes).